# My domain does not show up in any SEO analysis websites

Tags: seo, google-search-console

My client's domain worktrak.in seems to be totally invisible in the SEO analysis websites. Like for example when we query the domain "worktrak.in" for the following...

1. Organic keywords
2. Organic monthly keywords
3. Organic monthly traffic
4. Domain score
5. Backlinks

None of these return any results. I have tried in multiple SEO related websites like

1. NeilPatel.com
2. SemRush
3. Moz
4. SeRanking.com

I am unable to understand why this domain is not being queried by these above sites for the details. While I am able to get the details from google analytics and search console.

Can anyone help on this please?

Comment: If the domain is invisible, my guess is that it's not big enough. For more details, I'd consider asking each of those sites individually why your site doesn't show up on their service.

Comment: ICANN whois lookup for that domain gives this message.. No registry RDAP server was identified for this domain. Attempting lookup using WHOIS service.Failed to perform lookup using WHOIS service: TLD_NOT_SUPPORTED. Could this be the issue?

Comment: Probably not. Just make sure it shows up if you do a direct query with the .in registry: https://www.registry.in/whois

Answer (score 1):

I have looked up that domain and I think your domain seems is too younger to get ranked by 3rd party SEO analysis/software. based on my experience, 3rd party SEO software gets your data up to 1 year after first indexed on google. But usually only 4 or 5 months, it depends on how much the web quality or other factors.